# Conditionally write open graph meta property in header

Tags: functions, facebook, open-graph

Have a function I use to print Open Graph tags in the header of each page I also have a plugin I use to post to Facebook which also puts in it's own set of basic OG Tags. Facebook doesn't like if a page as more than one og:url tag. The plugin only works on single pages so I want to not print my og:url tag when it is on a single post page. I want to test for is_home and is_tag and if those are true the function will print the og:url tag. The other problem is the home page has a completely different url than the tag page. I tried doing the conditional inside the meta tag but Facebook vomits if the og:url line even exists.

Here is the code I currently have and everything except the conditional for the og:url tag is working:

```
    function wpc_fb_opengraph() {
$wpc_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),     'large');
?>
<?php echo "\n<!-- Start of OG Tags from DougTheme 2013 -->\n"; ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (function_exists('catch_that_image')) {echo catch_that_image(); }?>" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXXX"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXX">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); } else { echo "comments about everything"; } ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php if ( is_singular()) { echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); } elseif (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {single_tag_title('Tag Archive for &quot;'); echo '&quot; - '; echo get_bloginfo('name');} else { echo get_bloginfo('name'); } ?>">
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo "article"; } else { echo "website";} ?>">
        if (is_home()) {
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" />
<?php } //end if home

elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];  ?>">
<?php }      


<?php echo "\n<!-- End of OG Tags from DougTheme 2013 -->\n"; ?>
<?php }

add_action('wp_head', 'wpc_fb_opengraph');
```

I get a syntax error in either of the lines testing for the page. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need help framing your if logic? And the php tags usage dont look right either.

Does this help -

```
<?php 
if(!is_single()){
    if(is_home() || is_front_page()){ // not sure if you have set a static page as your front page
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.bloginfo('url'); .'" />';
    }elseif(is_tag()){
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; .'">';
        }
}
?>
```

=================== This is the code in entirety ========================

```
    function wpc_fb_opengraph() {
$wpc_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),     'large');
?>
<?php echo "\n<!-- Start of OG Tags from DougTheme 2013 -->\n"; ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (function_exists('catch_that_image')) {echo catch_that_image(); }?>" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXXX"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXX">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); } else { echo "comments about everything"; } ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php if ( is_singular()) { echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); } elseif (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {single_tag_title('Tag Archive for &quot;'); echo '&quot; - '; echo get_bloginfo('name');} else { echo get_bloginfo('name'); } ?>">
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo "article"; } else { echo "website";} ?>">
if(!is_single()){
    if(is_home() || is_front_page()){ // not sure if you have set a static page as your front page
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.bloginfo('url'); .'" />';
    }elseif(is_tag()){
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; .'">';
        }
}    

<?php echo "\n<!-- End of OG Tags from DougTheme 2013 -->\n"; ?>
<?php }    

add_action('wp_head', 'wpc_fb_opengraph');
```

Comment: When I put that code into my function I got a syntax error on the first meta property line for an unexpected '.'

Comment: How do I merge that logic code into my function - that is the problem I'm having. The conditionals inside the meta property lines work fine but when I try to put the conditional outside of that statement I get syntax errors.

Comment: It is printing the if else line at the top of my page so at least no syntax error. Here is a link to my page that I want this to work on. http://is.gd/s2ufPe

Comment: Go it to work by making some minor changes. Thanks for the leading me to the solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code to solve my issue.

```
    <?php if(!is_single()){
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){ // not sure if you have set a static page as your front page
    echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.get_bloginfo('url').'" />';
}elseif(is_tag()){
    echo '<meta property="og:url" content="http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].' ">';
    }
```

}
?>

I added this block to my function and it does what I need it to do - write the url of the page depending if it was the home page or a tag page.

The final issue was getting syntax errors with the data inside the echo statements so I used a PHP code checker to knock those down.